# linux distro won't boot after installing alongside existing linux distro

Tags: grub2, manjaro

I have an existing working version (the one I am writing from)
of Linux Manjaro on `/dev/sda2` partition (root) as can be seen:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0   100G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0   500G  0 part /home
├─sda4   8:4    0   512M  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0 111.1G  0 part
└─sda6   8:6    0 219.9G  0 part
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Few hours ago I installed another Linux distro (Manjaro also, but some other
flavour) on `/dev/sda5` with `home` mounted on `/dev/sda6`.

Installation went fine. No problems.

After reboot however, when I try to boot into my newly installed linux,
I am getting the following error, and I am not even able to type anything on
my keyboard, as system is totally unresponsive and freezed.

[image]

This is what I have in my Grub menu entry if I pres `e` to edit loader:

[image]

Not sure, why this is happening, if `/dev/sda5` is the root partition of a
newly installed system, and is spcified by UUID too.. Maybe someone can give
some directions on how to resolve this.

Comment: When the keyboard freezes, it's usually that the installed kernel version doesn't get along with the hardware, or perhaps needs some boot-time config option.

Comment: But that same distro runs fine from live-usb.. it's Manjaro Deepin distro by the way.

Comment: The kernel version on the live-usb might not be the same as the one on the hard drive.  Suppose the live-usb is a few weeks old, during setup, it might ask for permission to upgrade the software before installing, if it upgrades the kernel, the hard drive gets an different version.  OR, the live-usb might be using the most conservative possible kernel boot parameters, while the hard disk install might be using the less conservative package installer's default parameters.

Comment: Just tried with previous version 15.12, and it boots fine.. so I guess something is wrong with kernel itself or maybe the thing that the menu items for booting differ a bit between the two.

Answer (score 0):

A *general* outline.  Use a [rescue bootCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs#Rescue_and_repair_live_CDs) to either:

1. boot from */dev/sda5* via the bootCD's copy of **grub**, or whatever boot manager it uses.
2. failing that, `chroot` to */dev/sda5*, and correct things from the *chroot*.

Either way it'll probably take a few cycles of:

- bootCD boot manager
- boot or *chroot* to */dev/sda5*
- finish any pending installation
- maybe downgrade or upgrade kernel and rerun `update-grub`
- reboot *without* bootCD
- repeat as needed